# Getting "Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed" when click on a EditText

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext

I am trying to add a EditText to a fragment. This is my xml file of the fragment, `

```
<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left|top">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/input_layout_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="157dp">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:hint="Mobile Number"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

`
When I click on the EditText, my text pad does not appear. And shows,

```
Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
```

If I click it again and again it gives,

```
Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
```

from the second time onward. Somebody please help me to solve this problem. Sorry for the English, if you need further details please ask and do not mark it as minus.

Comment: On which API are you testing..? Is your `EditText` in a `ListView`? Do you use a `ListFragment`?

Comment: @Amy it is android 5.1 API

Comment: No. It is just an `EditText` and I use `android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout` layout

Comment: What `Theme` are you using? Might be related to [this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=106564) problem. Also, please post more relevant code, your `xml` seems to be ok.

Comment: @Amy thank you for your replies. I figured it out. The error was with my `android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/spinner"`

Comment: No problem, happy coding. :)